# Yii2: Easy way to render page size selector at the paginator

Tags: yii2, paginator

Is there any easy and native way to add html rendering of items per page selector to the paginator at the ListView ? I've looked through the docs:

1. [Yii widget listview](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview)
2. [Yii data pagination](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination)
3. [Yii widgets linkpager](http://%20https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager)

Found everything I need, except rendering the page size selector. This is a bit strange, as this is a very common feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there were no native way to do this, you can create your own or use this one:

Define in your model filter:

```
    class YOUR_CLASS_FILTER extend YOUR_MODEL
       
    
        ...
           public $pagesize; // Property pagesize.
           const ITEMS_PER_PAGE_INIT = 12; // Initial items per page
           ...
        
           //Add or edit this in the same model `search` method:
           public function search($params){    
           ...
           $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                    'query' => $query,
                    'pagination' => [
                        // this $params['pagesize'] is an id of dropdown list that we set in view file
                        'pagesize' => ($this->pagesize) ? $this->pagesize : self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE_INIT,
                    ],
                ]);
           ...
           }    
           ... 
           public function rules()
            {
                return [
                    ...
                    [['pagesize'], 'integer'],
                    ...
                ];
            }
            ...
    /**
     * Return Static Array of elements per page
     * @return array
     */
    public static function itemsPerPage()
    {
        return array(
            12 => 12,
            24 => 24,
            48 => 48
        );
    }
}
```

This is how i implemented in view file:

```
<?= $form->field($filter, 'pagesize')->dropDownList(
    $filter->itemsPerPage(),
    array(
      'id' => 'pagesize',
      'class' => 'form-control',
      'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()',
    ))->label("Items per page: ")
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a menu with links to current page with the different per-page options as GET parameter:

```
<ul>
    <li><?= yii\helpers\Html::a('10', yii\helpers\Url::current(['per-page' => 10])) ?></li>
    <li><?= yii\helpers\Html::a('25', yii\helpers\Url::current(['per-page' => 25])) ?></li>
    <li><?= yii\helpers\Html::a('50', yii\helpers\Url::current(['per-page' => 50])) ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This solution is also suitable. Thanks!